# How to perform date_trunc query in Postgres using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I can't seem to be able to translate the following query into SQLAlchemy.

I would like to translate the following query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', time), "PositionReport".callsign FROM tvh_aircraft."PositionReport" WHERE "PositionReport".reg = 'PH-BVA'
GROUP BY 1, "PositionReport".callsign
```

I've tried the following, but with no luck.

```
flight_days = session\
        .query(PositionReport)\
        .filter(PositionReport.reg == reg) \
        .group_by(func.date_trunc('day', PositionReport.time))\
        .group_by('1')\
        .all()

    trunc_date = func.date_trunc('day', PositionReport.time)
    flight_days = session.query(trunc_date, PositionReport.callsign) \
        .filter(PositionReport.reg == reg) \
        .group_by("date_trunc_1")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, could you post some examples of the data and the desired output?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
session.query(func.date_trunc('day', PositionReport.time), 
              PositionReport.callsign) \
    .filter(PositionReport.reg=='PH-BVA') \
    .group_by(func.date_trunc('day', PositionReport.time),
              PositionReport.callsign).all()
```

or if you need exactly `GROUP BY 1`

```
from sqlalchemy import text

session.query(func.date_trunc('day', PositionReport.time), 
              PositionReport.callsign) \
    .filter(PositionReport.reg=='PH-BVA') \
    .group_by(text('1'),
              PositionReport.callsign).all()
```

Comment: Thanks. Does indeed work. For other people reading this, only add .all() to the query to make it complete.